# Skewed distribution based on a Normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

Let us assume the intelligence quotient of a human being is modelled by ~N(100,15^2). We have country X with average of 103 (this is the only information we have). How can we then estimate the IQ of a random person in the top 1% of people in country X?

Comment: "Let us assume the intelligence quotient of an average human being is modelled by ~N(100,15^2). "  If the human being is average, then the distribution of IQ will not have extreme tails. Indeed, to use the term average in its formal sense as the mean, the IQ of the average human being is by definition 100 (and not random).

Comment: @wolfies i shall change it to 'a human being' then, thanks

Comment: You know that the mean is wrong, so (clearly) the distribution must change but there doesn't appear to be information on *how* it changes. You would be left then to assume some form of change in distribution (e.g. are you just going to assume that the mean moves up but the variability and the shape don't change? It's convenient but it's not clear that it's necessarily the most realistic assumption)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have no basis for estimating the standard deviation of IQs in Country X. So maybe you just want to assume that in Country X IQ scores have the 'customary' standard deviation $\sigma = 15.$  Then maybe you'd want the 99th percentile of $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 103, \sigma = 15),$ which is just below IQ $138,$ according
to R.

```
qnorm(.99, 103, 15)
[1] 137.8952
```

With so little information provided, there must be a dozen or so answers that are
equally good---perhaps except for simplicity.